# Drag, clone drop and resize after dropped

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Excuse me, because i am new but every attend to implement the resizable functionality of dropped clones of Images fail.
So what do i want to do? i want to drag and drop some images from a list in a div in another drop-field and after they were dropped i want them to be resizable.
i clone my images and i can only resize/change the originals images.

So here is my code:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
helper: 'clone',
cursor: 'move',
snap: '#droppable',
revert:"invalid"
});
$(".draggable").resizable({
});

$("#droppable").droppable({

drop: function (e, ui) {
if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
x = ui.helper.clone();
ui.helper.remove();
x.draggable({
helper: 'ui-resizable-helper',
containment: '#droppable',
tolerance: 'fit'
});

x.appendTo('#droppable');
}

}
});
```

And here is the Jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UkvVy/11/

I also made an alternative code. i am too bad to add ther resizable and fadeout options on the dropped and cloned objects. as i experimented with the clones every time i click on the clone to drag it again a clone is being made.

My alternative code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


   //Make element draggable
$(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert:'invalid'
    }).on('dragstart', function (e, ui) {
$(ui.helper).css('z-index','999999');
}).on('dragstop', function (e, ui) {
$(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
}); 


  $("#droppable").resizable({
         grid: [10000, 1]
     });

var x = null;
$("#droppable").droppable({
accept: '.draggable',
drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().attr("id", "id1").draggable({
      containment: '#droppable',
        cursor: 'move',
        snap: '#droppable'}));
      $(this).addClass("item");
      $(this).removeClass("ui-helper item");
      $(this).resizable();
      $(".item").dblclick(function() {
   $(this).fadeOut('slow');
 });
       }

});
});
```

In this Jsfiddle everything works fine....

http://jsfiddle.net/UkvVy/18/

Update:

I tried to make an alternative Code and i got the same errors. As soon as i add $clone.resizable the draggable ability after a drop fails.

But in this JSfiddle everything works again...
http://jsfiddle.net/UkvVy/45/

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

$(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
        if (!$clone.is('.inside-droppable')) {
            $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-droppable').draggable({
                containment: '.droppable',
                tolerance: 'fit',
                position: 'relaitve'
            }));

            $clone.resizable({ //this works but I dont want it to on outside elements
                animate: 'true',
                ghost: 'true',
                handles:     'ne, nw, se, sw',
            });



        }
    }
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert:"invalid"
});


});
```